# Is it possible to pass a "Enter Parameter Value" to form if query fails?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I was working with an Access 2013 database and had a question about the "Enter Parameter Value" box. I am using a Form whose record source is tied to a "Select" query.

If the query finds the result I'm looking for, it populates the form with its values. If the query fails, it keeps the form blank for a new entry to be made by users.

Some of my users have been complaining that they'd like to pass the value they initially put into "Enter Parameter Value" to the form if the query fails so they don't have to enter data twice into the form.

Is it possible to pass a value from "Enter Parameter Value" to the form box instead of too a query?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be enter the value in a form box and then programmatically pass the value as parameter to your query.

some pseudo:

- Open the querydef
- Set the parameter value
- Set the query as form's rowSource

Some code:

check here:
http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/887449-how-pass-parameter-value-query-via-vba

Comment: The technique in your link link is out of date. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

in Access 2010 and 2013

This uses DAO and might be of interest

```
DIM MyQryDef as querydef
Dim a as string 

a = ""

a = a & "PARAMETERS Parameter1 INT, Parameter2 INT; "

a = a & "SELECT f1, f2 FROM atable WHERE "
a = a & "f3 = [Parameter1] AND f4 = [Parameter2] "
a = a & ";"

Set MyQryDef = currentdb().CreateQueryDef("MyQueryName", a)

MyQryDef.Parameters("Parameter1").Value = 33
MyQryDef.Parameters("Parameter2").Value = 2

' You could now use MyQryDef with DAO recordsets

' to use it with any of OpenQuery, BrowseTo , OpenForm, OpenQuery, OpenReport, or RunDataMacro


DoCmd.SetParameter "Parameter1", 33
DoCmd.SetParameter "Parameter2", 2
DoCmd.Form YourFormName
```

' or

```
DoCmd.SetParameter "Parameter1", 33
DoCmd.SetParameter "Parameter2", 2
DoCmd.OpenQuery MyQryDef.Name
```

See here:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194182(v=office.14).aspx](http://here)

Harvey